# ¿Cómo pasar de caso de prueba al fallar?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

estoy intentando automatizar unas pruebas, que al fallar un step no continuar con los scenarios de prueba.
He intentado en usar:

```
driver().close(); /quit();
```

Pero me cierra el navegador y no me ejecuta ningún caso más. Mi proyecto tiene un framework que cuando falle un step, continue con todos los scenarios de pruebas de mi gherkin. Quisiera omitir esos pasos para que pase al siguiente test.

Por ejemplo, si ejecuto 5steps y me falla el primero, los demás steps no se ejecutan.

Que puedo hacer? Hay alguna solución?
Gracias a tod@s

Answer (score 0):

Estimado de acuerdo a documentacion oficial y buena practica,  debes utilizar los assertion.

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
El **fail** aplica en tu caso.

Nota: Debe añadir los before y after como hooks.

Saludos.

Comment: Buenas, gracias por la idea. Estoy usando los after y before para hooks. El problema si uso el Assert.fail, no me deja continuar el step siguiente

Comment: Es que en cierta manera si la prueba por ejemplo no detecta el elemento en X step no deberia continuar, luego entras a revisar y si es causado por desarrollo , debes reportar. Luego dev arreglan y vuelves a correr las pruebas y si pasa. Todo bien. Si quieres hacer que las prueban avancen aunque falle en el step. Agrega un try catch. Saludos.

Comment: Eso es lo que quiero, que pare la prueba y no continúe con el siguiente scenario pero no me deja lanzar la siguiente prueba. Si por ejemplo tengo dos Test de pruebas, si falla el primero el 2 no se lanza. ¿ se puede hacer algo? ¿ tengo que crear otro xml para ejecutar individuales y no en paralelo? Gracias de nuevo, saludos!

Comment: Buenas de nuevo @Alex Bravo. Tengo una pregunta.... ¿Puede ser que al usar en un caso el fail() continúe al siguiente scenario porque estoy trabajando con multihilo y está configurada de otra manera?. Si es eso el problema (yo creo que si) que solución debo tener para que me falle el scenario y continue con otro feature?

Comment: Con el fail te fallará en el step y el scenario no va a continuar

Comment: Perdona de nuevo, ya he visto porque no me permite fallar los scenarios, tengo la versión del core 7 y los @test están llamando a io.cucumber.testng.Pickle pickle, no se si sabes como decir que falle. Esa clase son .class y se genera automatico, no creo que pueda modificar

Comment: Buenas de nuevo, he visto la solución. Paso la URL para que todos tengamos respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/572538/assume-assumetrue-finalizar-scenarios-y-continuar-con-el-siguiente-step