# Assume.assumeTrue - Finalizar scenarios y continuar con el siguiente Step

Tags: java, selenium, java-8, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Estoy intentando que, al detectar un fallo en un scenario de feature de cucumber, termine ese step y continúe con el siguiente step. Solo he logrado que falle el step pero no continua con el siguiente step. Por ejemplo, si lanzo 3 casos de pruebas y fallo el primero, debe continuar con el siguiente caso. Este es mi código:

```
public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario){
if(scenario.status.equals("FAILED")){
  RunMainTest.valorB = false;
  Assume.assumeTrue(RunMainTest.valorB);
  }
}
//hooks
@Before(order=1)
public final void Step(Scenario scenario){

        String[] listSc = scenario.getSourceTagNames().toString().split(";");

        for (int i=0; i<listSc.length;i++){
            System.out.println("for_array "+listSc[i]);
            if (listSc[i].equals(scenario.getSourceTagNames().toString())){
                System.out.println("dentro");
                Assume.assumeTrue(RunMainTest.valorB);
            }else {
                RunMainTest.valorB = true;
                Assume.assumeTrue(RunMainTest.valorB);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ya tengo la solución.
Este metodo, se llama al BaseContext, al sacar la captura de pantalla:

```
 /**
     * This method when returning true the 'stop.fail', the scenario stops and continues with the next step.
     *
     * If the 'stop.fail' property returns false, this method is not executed
     */
    protected void stopFailed() {
            // If the 'stop.fail' is true, the variable Assume.assumeTrue is executed
            if (Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("stop.fail"))){
                 ClassInjector.getSharedContent().setValorScenario(false);
            }
    }
```

Este metodo, llama a la clase Hooks, al metodo @before(order=1), para que al llamar el scenario sea diferente pase al siguiente step:

```
/**
     * This method, will finish (or not) the execution of the gherkin test.
     * It depends on stop fail value. If stop fail value is selected as true, it will
     * finish it, otherwise, it won't.
     * @param scenario current scenario value from cucumber framework.
     */
    public void stopScenarioExecution(Scenario scenario) {
        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("stop.fail"))) {
            //This conditional, will check if we are trying to execute a new Gherkin Test.
            if (!ClassInjector.getSharedContent().getTagNameStore().equals(scenario.getSourceTagNames().toString())) {
                ClassInjector.getSharedContent().setTagNameStore(scenario.getSourceTagNames().toString());
                ClassInjector.getSharedContent().setValorScenario(true);
            }
            //If Valor Scenario is false, assume will throw an exception, and it will finish the execution of the scenario.
            if (!ClassInjector.getSharedContent().isValorScenario()) {
                Assume.assumeTrue(ClassInjector.getSharedContent().isValorScenario());
            }
        }
    }
```